# Adding built angular project to Docker based on nginx is very slow

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have an Angular project. I build it with `ng build --prod`. Then I build a docker container based on nginx container. Only things I add to this docker container is the dist folder with it's contents and nginx.conf. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

In my dist folder there is not much. Usual minified js target files and no more than 1MB of other assets like pictures.
Now if I run `docker build .` then it takes sometimes up to 10 minutes for any logs to appear and then I get the "sending build contect to daemon" etc and finally a success. What I've noticed is that it takes those 10 minutes if I change something in my Angular project and rebuild the project.

So the flow is:

```
$ docker build .
(something happening here, it just does something without any logs for 10 minutes)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  627.5MB
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx
Step 2/3 : COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> e831f2851f75
Step 3/3 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> f6264feec52b
```

**So my question is what is halting Docker for such a long time and how can I make it quicker?**

Comment: You can add a `.dockeringore` file in your project to ignore your `node_modules` directory as it's usually huge and could take a lot of time to send it to the build process.

Comment: My node_modules is not in the build context. Only the dist  folder is and node_modules is not in the dist folder. Or it affects stuff just because it's in the same folder as my Dockerfile even though I dont add it to docker?

Comment: The build context is the directory specified by the `docker build` command. It's the last parameter. Docker take all the build context and after apply the build command on it (like `COPY dist /usr/...`)

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thank you so much. Now I've got my release pipeline from 11 minutes to just 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're talking about your Angular app it's probably the build context which is checked.

Make sure to ignore the files you won't need for your build to improve performance by adding a `.dockerignore` file to your build.

The Docker build context (in your case `.`, which is the current directory) is uploaded to the Docker Daemon.

> That means that all the files at PATH get sent, not just the ones listed to ADD in the Dockerfile.

See [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path)

If you exclude the `node_modules` folder and any other unnecessary large directories/files it's likely that your build is way faster.

---

Additionally some best practises

```
# add git-ignore syntax here of things you don't want copied into docker image

.git
*Dockerfile*
*docker-compose*
node_modules
```

By [Docker Captain Bret Fisher - Good dockerignore defaults](https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/master/.dockerignore)